# pylatex: how to apply {\centering <x> } around graphics and or text?

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

I am trying to create the following (type of) code with PyLatex:

```
{
     \centering
     \includegraphics{image.png}
     \includegraphics{image.png}
}
```

I am not able to 'group' the `\centering` command with the curly brackets around the `\includegraphics`; if I define a new Environment, I always end up with `\begin` and `\end` which add spacing.

So, do you know how I can nicely add the curly brackets with the `\centering` command around a snippet of code like `\includegrahics`?

To me, the most elegant solution would be something like:

```
with doc.centering():
    doc.append('Some text.')
    append(StandAloneGraphic(image))
    append(StandAloneGraphic(image2))
```

How can I define such '''with doc.centering()''' command? Of course, I can hard code this every time, but I want my code to be readable so it would be nice if I could write a nice function for this problem.

I posted this question earlier om Stack Exchange (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490429/pylatex-how-to-apply-centering-x-around-graphic/490442), but over there I got the advice to post here because it is more of a Python programming problem than a PyLatex challenge.

Update: I would like to put teh code below in a nice `with.group():` statement:

```
import pylatex as pl

doc = pl.Document()
doc.preamble.append(pl.Package('showframe'))

doc.append(pl.NoEscape('{'))
doc.append(pl.Command('centering'))
doc.append(pl.StandAloneGraphic('example-image',image_options='width=5cm'))
doc.append(pl.Command('par'))
doc.append(pl.NoEscape('}'))

doc.generate_tex('pylatexdemo')
```

This piece of code creates the correct output, but is not really readable. I would imagine such solution (but I don't know how to program it); the definition of the `group`-function is incorrect. My question is: how to implement such `group`-function?

```
import pylatex as pl


doc = pl.Document()
doc.preamble.append(pl.Package('showframe'))

def group(content):
    doc.append(pl.NoEscape('{'))
    doc.append(content)  
    doc.append(pl.Command('par'))
    doc.append(pl.NoEscape('}'))

with doc.group():
    doc.append(pl.Command('centering'))
    doc.append(pl.StandAloneGraphic('example-image',image_options='width=5cm'))

doc.generate_tex('pylatexdemo')
```

Comment: The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490442/36296 makes me wonder if the whole problem boils down to the fact that `{}` are "used otherwise" by python. I don't know pylatex,  so the following is just a crude guess, but could you try something like: `doc.append('Some text.')
    doc.append(pl.Command('begingroup')) doc.append(pl.Command('centering'))
    append(StandAloneGraphic(image))
    doc.append(pl.Command('endgroup'))` ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could crate a short example document to give us something to play with.

Comment: Hi @samcarter, I just updated the qustion. Is that clear for you? So, I know how the get the correct result, but I would like to have a little bit 'nicer' solution to make my code look much more clean and like other PyLatex statements (for example adding sections)

Answer (score 0):

The PyLaTeX `Center` environment may help you: https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/pylatex/pylatex.position.html#pylatex.position.Center . To make two centered figures, one atop the other:

```
from pylatex.position import Center
from pylatex.utils import NoEscape
from pylatex.basic import LineBreak

with doc.create(Center()) as environment:
    environment.append(NoEscape(r'\includegraphics{''image.png''}'))
    environment.append(LineBreak())
    environment.append(NoEscape(r'\includegraphics{''image.png''}'))
```